# cannot use this in a static context activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to implement a new class that shows an alertdialog  but when I moved the code from the original activity to another class to implement it anywhere in the app it says on the alertDialog.builder line (cannot use this in a static context )

```
public class showDialog {

static final String[] items = {"Facebook" ,"flicker" , "Google"};
static boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length] ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

and when I tried changing it to refrence the activity that I want

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

It says (No eclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope)

what's the solution ??

Comment: You need to pass a `Context` to the constructor of that class and use that instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reason for the error***

You will not be able to access the context of another activity (Activity 2) from Activity 1 just with Activity2.this.

To access the dialog alert class across activities, you should pass the activity context to the alert dialog class.

***Example***

### Assumption

Class for showing the dialog - myclass

Activities which like to show dialog - Activity1, Activity2

### To implement

myClass(Context theContext, ...) and

in Activity1 and Activity2

myClass(this, ...);

Answer (score 0):

You in a class and apparently it isn't an `Activity`. To build an `AlertDialog` you need a `Context`.

- `this` isn't an `Activity` so it isn't a `Context`.
- `MainActivity.this` isn't a `Context` too.

You need to call this function with a parameter of the type `Context` like this.

**In your class**

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context ctx) {
    // SOME CODE
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    // SOME CODE
}
```

**In your activity**

```
myClass.showAlertDialog(this);
```